# How to solve 'ERROR: md5sum mismatch (08731075489d1776b9c0f2f109f01552 != ed33d32bdbf3f37f03c8f407209bfa47) on build/FF-v2.3.tgz; aborting'?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [pddl_planner](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=pddl_planner).

I use ROS electric and run:

```
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/pddl/pddl_planner
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/3rdparty/ff
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/3rdparty/ffha
  svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/pddl/pddl_msgs
```

Then I rosmake:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/ai/pddl/pddl_planner$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['pddl_planner']                                                          
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pddl_planner']                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-224210                                 
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pddl_planner'] to:
  ['pddl_planner']                                                       
  [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages pddl_planner.  This may take a few seconds.                      
  [ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
   No Makefile in package rosbuild                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
   No Makefile in package roslang                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits                                           
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                             
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization                             
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                                     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs                                           
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean                                                     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                              
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                               
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                                                           
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                            
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam                                                     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                           
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster                                                   
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                             
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                                                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs                                         
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> ff [ make ]                                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] All 7 linesroscpp: 2.3 sec ] [ ff: 2.1 sec ]                                   [ 2 Active 19/28 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mkdir -p build
    if [ ! -f FF-v2.3.tgz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file FF-v2.3.tgz.md5sum" && false; fi
    `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py http://www.loria.fr/~hoffmanj/ff/FF-v2.3.tgz build/FF-v2.3.tgz `awk {'print $1'} FF-v2.3.tgz.md5sum`
    [rosbuild] Downloading http://www.loria.fr/~hoffmanj/ff/FF-v2.3.tgz to build/FF-v2.3.tgz...Done
    [rosbuild] Checking md5sum on build/FF-v2.3.tgz
    [rosbuild] ERROR: md5sum mismatch (08731075489d1776b9c0f2f109f01552 != ed33d32bdbf3f37f03c8f407209bfa47) on build/FF-v2.3.tgz; aborting
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package ff written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-224210/ff/build_output.log
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< ff [FAIL] [ 2.16 seconds ]                                                                   
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ff. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp [PASS] [ 11.29 seconds ]                                                              
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] Built 21 packages with 1 failures.                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                               
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-224210                                                     
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/ai/pddl/pddl_planner$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42282/how-to-solve-%27error:-md5sum-mismatch-(08731075489d1776b9c0f2f109f01552-!=-ed33d32bdbf3f37f03c8f407209bfa47)-on-build/ff-v2.3.tgz;-aborting%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That url appears to no longer exist.

```
Le site du LORIA a changé. Le lien que vous avez sélectionné n'est plus valide.

Pour retrouver l'ensemble des rubriques, connectez vous sur la page d'accueil : http://www.loria.fr

En cas de problème, contactez : comm@loria.fr
```

Google Translate says:

```
LORIA site has changed. The link you selected is no longer valid.

To find all the items, log on to the homepage: http://www.loria.fr

In case of problems, please contact: comm@loria.fr
```

You'll need to contact the original author or find the new tarball url.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0